# exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup EjbDeployer load method

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ejb, glassfish-3

exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup EjbDeployer load method
this exception is result of using TimerService scheduleexpression in eclipse indigo with glassfish
its an error at deployment time
Any body can help me

Comment: Provide little more stacktrace content, properly formatted & expression used. Have you tried removing expression, does the application gets properly deployed thereafter.